# Wordpress: Remove view link from a category actions row

Tags: wordpress

How can I remove the "view" action from a wordpress category?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Lrnql8S.png]

I need a PHP function to add into theme's `functions.php`; no jQuery please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that prints that is in [`wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php#L438)
Adding this to your theme's `functions.php` removes the `View` link:

```
add_filter( 'category_row_actions', function($actions,$tag) {
  unset($actions['view']);
  return $actions;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I remove it from a specific custom post?

Comment: That's another question, but you can follow the same approach by using the hook [in this file](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L1229).

Answer (score 0):

you should try {$taxonomy}_row_actions action, 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_row_actions-2/.

That should let you modify the links for specified taxonomy.